# onSaveInstanceState, subsequent outState.putInt statement overwrites previous value

Tags: android

I have written this very simple code. `STATE_SCORE 1` and `STATE_SCORE_2` are  declared as static final strings, initialised to `null`;

The problem is, `score1` is always overwritten by `score2`, i.e. if i make `score1 = 5` and `score2 = 6` then rotate the screen, both outputs will be 6.

If I comment out anything to do with `score2`, `score1` works fine, I have even parsed `score2` to a string so i could use `outState.putString()` instead, the result was the same, `score2` overwrites `score1`. 
I used `Log.d` beneath `outState.putInt(STATE_SCORE_2, score2)` to see where `score1` was being overwritten, calling `STATE_SCORE_1` with `getInt()` shows the output matching `score2`...

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //Save the scores
    outState.putInt(STATE_SCORE_1, score1);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SCORE_2, score2);
    Log.d("score1",String.valueOf(outState.getInt(STATE_SCORE_1)));
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and then within the onCreate method;

```
    //restore the saved instance state if one exists
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        score1 = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE_1);
        score2 = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE_2);

        //Set the score text views
        mScore1Tv.setText(String.valueOf(score1));
        mScore2Tv.setText(String.valueOf(score2));
    }
```

Comment: Possibly STATE_SCORE_1 and STATE_SCORE_2 points to same constant value?

Comment: Hi rhavelka, please elaborate, im not sure i understand your comment, you can see that both keys are unique so how can they point to the same constant value?

Comment: @SteveC I didn't comment on your post. I just edited it so that variables and functions in your post are easily seen. But your code looks good. Could you possibly add how you are initializing `score1` and `score2`?

Comment: Hi rhavelka, both are simply declared and initialised as usual;                        
    private int score1 = 0;
    private int score2 = 0; As a reminder, if i comment out everything to do with score2, score1 works fine